# how to compare all the tables schemas and report missing columns in two oracle databases

Tags: oracle

i Have one server and two databases. I have to create a db link and make sure both the databases are in sync comparing all columns and alter the missing columns in tables of database two. I m new to oracle and have to do this via script only no third party tools allowed. Note i m comparing 20 tables in two databases

```
select t1.column_name t1, t2.column_name t2,t1.table_name
from
(select * from all_tab_columns where table_name like '%EMND%') t1
full outer join 
(select * from all_tab_columns where table_name like '%EMND%') t2
on t1.column_name = t2.column_name 

where (t1.column_name is null or t2.column_name is null)
```

Found these two queries

```
select      a.table_name , a.column_name , a.data_type , a.data_length , 
            b.table_name , b.column_name , b.data_type , b.data_length
from        all_tab_columns a full outer join all_tab_columns b 
on          (a.column_name = b.column_name)
where       a.owner = 'OWNER_A'
and         a.table_name = 'TABLE_A'
and         b.owner = 'OWNER_B'
and         b.table_name = 'TABLE_B'
```

Comment: Is there a question?  Are these queries not doing what you want?  If so, can you describe the problem?

Comment: i have made this query `code`select t1.column_name t1, t2.column_name t2,t1.table_name
from
(select * from all_tab_columns where table_name like '%EMND_TBLEMANDATE_ARCH%') t1
full outer join 
(select * from all_tab_columns where table_name like '%EMND_TBLEMANDATE_ARCH1%') t2
on t1.column_name = t2.column_name 
where (t1.column_name is null or t2.column_name is null) here i have hardcoded the table name and is in same database i want to compare all tables in different databases`code`

Comment: I think that is the first query you posted in your question but it's hard to tell.  Your question says that you know you need to create a database link.  I assume you are aware that you'd need one of the two `all_tab_columns` references to use that newly created database link if you want to compare the structure of a table in the local database with the structure of the table in the remote database.

Comment: yes i am aware FROM   user_tab_columns@my_db_link i just want to understand is the query right to compare all tables as i dont have a second database yet

Comment: Both queries appear plausible.  I don't know if they provide exactly the data you want in exactly the format that you want.  You're not joining on the owner or table name which may be fine if your `like` returns a single table name (in which case it would make more sense to do an =) and if you don't care about the schema name.  You're not comparing the data type, length, precision, etc. just the column name which may or may not be what you want.  The results may or may not be in the format you want.